# Is there a way to write vertically on a web console (dev tools)?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-devtools, console.log, web-inspector

I come to the need to write vertically on a web console for output some traditional Chinese characters. Is there a way to write vertically on the web console from the browser (dev tools)?

**Note:** I'm not asking how to do this inside a div/html page. I'm looking how to do it on the web console.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible solution I know is to use `\n` for new lines.

Do you have a more specific context to look at?

`console.log('信\n信')`

which will generate in the console: `信
信`

Comment: I don't following any really, I was looking on how to achieve such thing. I have look everywhere but still I can't find it